# Сравнить два массива js

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить два массива и если элемента нету, то добавить в него из другого?
Пример:

> arr[1,2,3,4,5]
>   tempDates[6,7,8]

Если `tempDates[i] !== arr[j]` добавляем, чтобы получить

> tempDates[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

```
for (var i = 0; i < tempDates.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if(tempDates.length == arr.length) {
            return true;
        } else if (tempDates.length !== arr.length) {
            if(tempDates[i] !== arr[j]){
                tempDates.push(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам по условию задачи не нужно проверять если массивы одинаковой длинны? Зачем вы проверяете два раза равенство длинны  (если первое условие не выполняется вы переходите на else. И опять "а точно ли они не равны" хотя и ставите более жесткое условие)?  Почему вы добавляете индекс элемента, а не сам элемент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5],
    tempDates = [6,7,8];

for (var i = 0; i < tempDates.length; i++) {
  if (arr.indexOf(tempDates[i]) === -1) {
    arr.push(tempDates[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если в первоначальном массиве, нет дублей, то можно проще

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] //Инициализируем массивы
tempDates = [6, 7, 8]

tempDates.forEach(elem => arr.push(elem))  // Добавляем каждый элемент из массива 1 в массив 2
arr = [...new Set(arr)]  // Оставляем в массиве только уникальные значения

console.log(arr) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

создадим функцию проверки элементов массива на уникальность

```
function arrayUnique(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
       }
   }

   return a;
 }
```

выполним эту функцию от объединенных масивов

```
var res = arrayUnique(arr.concat(tempDates));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: если исходный массив был `[1,1,1]` этот способ не сработает